Why do I receive an Error code for my custom function?
I can't use add-ons, so I tried to write my own code to to use GPT with Google Sheets.
The error code that comes out is:
TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading '0') (line 30).
Line 30 is:
  console.log(response.choices[0].message.content);

Here's the full code:
function GPT(Input) {
  const GPT_API = "INSERT API KEY";
  const BASE_URL = "https://api.openai.com/v1/chat/completions";
  const headers = {
    "Content-Type": "application/json",
    "Authorization": `Bearer ${GPT_API}`
  };
  const options = {
    headers,
    method: "POST",
    muteHttpExceptions: true,
    payload: JSON.stringify({
      "model": "gpt-4",
      "messages": [
        {
          "role": "system",
          "content": ""
        },
        {
          "role": "user",
          "content": Input
        }
      ],
      "temperature": 0
    })
  }
  const response = JSON.parse(UrlFetchApp.fetch(BASE_URL, options));
  console.log(response.choices[0].message.content);
  return response.choices[0].message.content
}

The code worked at first, but the second I tried applying it in many cells at the same time it stopped.
I also tried the GPTforSheets add-on prior to using this code but add-ons don't work for me right now.

The error message indicates that there is no choices property in response, or that it is not an array.
To check whether the response is valid, and find its structure, replace the last three lines with these:
  const response = JSON.parse(UrlFetchApp.fetch(BASE_URL, options));
  const test = JSON.stringify(response);
  console.log(test);
  return test;

